¿Como puedo hacer que Google Maps haga un 'intent' a mi app?
Estoy intentando crear una app con .Net 8 MAUI y va a tener interacción con la app de Google Maps. Asi que necesito que cuando le oprima el boton de share aparezca entre las opciones mi app

Y que aparezca mi app en las opciones

Se que eso se hace por medio de  Intents  ya lo se hacer de mi app a Google Maps, pero ahora necesito lo contrario, y no se como puedo hacer.
Asi llevo mi AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:name="FirstApp.MainActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <!--
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="test" android:pathPrefix="/group" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/json" />
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="open.my.app" />-->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="maps.google.com" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="maps.google.com" />
                <data android:scheme="geo"/>
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>

Y el MainActivity.cs lo tento asi:
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;

namespace FirstApp
{
    [Activity(
        Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", 
        MainLauncher = true, 
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, 
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | 
            ConfigChanges.Orientation | 
            ConfigChanges.UiMode | 
            ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | 
            ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | 
            ConfigChanges.Density)]
    [IntentFilter(
        new string[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
        DataScheme = "https",
        DataHost = "maps.google.com",
        DataPath = "/recipe",
        AutoVerify = true)]

    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //test
            OnNewIntent(Intent);
            //Intent intent = getIntent();
            //Uri data = intent.getData(); // Here you will receive the URI

            //// ...
        }

        protected override async void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);

            var data = intent.DataString;

            if (intent.Action != Intent.ActionView) return;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data)) return;

            if (data.Contains("/group"))
            {
                //do what you want
            }
        }
    }
}

También he estado viendo la documentación Documentación Intents Microsoft pero hay muchas cosas que tengo en el aire.
Pd: apenas lo resuelva dejare actualización.
Gracias

Lectura recomendada: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/direct-share-targets
